# please can anybody help me out how to do the Spell check using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to implement Spell Check for my application using jquery,

Please can anyone help me out about this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of them is over here - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spellcheck

It uses Google spell checker API

Comment: @rockers - does it not suit your requirement?

Comment: Yes. Please could you help me out doing in jquery? i found the code but its not working for me at all..

Comment: @rockers - what do you need in your application? How is the spellchecker not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new one with good jQuery integration.  It has a full jQuery dialog, with undo functions, etc.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jspeller